PandasAI 'No such file or directory' error
While trying to save the plot from response, after a period of usage, pandasAI is throwing the 'No such file or directory' even when it was accessing the same directory to save the earlier plots.
Did anyone also encountered the issue and how can I solve it ?
I could not figure out the error at all as the path do exist.
